# How to switch to cuda7.5 after install tensorflow using .whl file?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have installed tensorflow using the 1.0.1 whl file.
When I run the command `python -c 'import tensorflow'` an import error says cannot open shared object file `libcublas.so8.0`.
However I have only cuda7.5 in my machine.

So how can I change tensorflow to use cuda7.5 in my machine??

Comment: You probably can't

Comment: can I set tensorflow to use cuda7.5 if I re-install it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [tensorflow website](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/get_started/os_setup):

> The GPU version works best with Cuda Toolkit 8.0 and cuDNN v5.1. Other
>   versions are supported (Cuda toolkit >= 7.0 and cuDNN >= v3) only when
>   installing from sources. Please see Cuda installation for details. For
>   Mac OS X, please see Setup GPU for Mac.

So, tensorflow will not work with cuda 7.5 when installed with the whl file.